# login website(kicktipp.de) with python request library

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to use python to login to a website (kicktipp.de). This is the following code I came up with by studying other stackoverflow question. Unfortunantelly for some reasons that I don't understand yet, it is not working. Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

```
import requests 
payload = {
    'kennung': 'name',
    'passwort': 'pw'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/profil/login', 
    data=payload)
    #print(p.text)
    r = s.get('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/tippuebersicht')
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before posting, you should get the page once, so that you get the session cookies, and re-transmit them.

Also you post to `login`, but you should post to `loginaction`

https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/profil/loginaction

And finally, you are missing the *charset* post parameter.

As a word of advice, when you try to do that, open the console in "network" tab.
Check "preserve log" (on chrome), and then do log in as you would normally.
In the console, you'll see every request being made.
The first one is the POST that you are trying to do, copy it as much as possible.

See : [image: google chrome developper tools - network]

```
import requests 
payload = {
    'kennung': 'name',
    'passwort': 'pw',
    '_charset_' : 'UTF-8'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/profil/login') # get session cookie
    p = s.post('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/profil/loginaction',
    data=payload) # login
    #print(p.text)
    r = s.get('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/tippuebersicht')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem and also for the really nice advice! :)

Answer (score 1):

The url to post to when you check the form action in the browser inspector is `/alternativlos/profil/loginaction`.

```
...
p = s.post('https://www.kicktipp.de/alternativlos/profil/loginaction',
...
```